# focal length computation from vanishing points

Tags: computer-vision

I am looking at a computer vision thesis here (http://www.itspy.cz/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/acmspy2014_submission_25.pdf) where the focal length computation for a camera system is given as:

```
f = sqrt(-(U - P) * (V - P))
```

where `U` and `V` are two vanishing points and `P` is the principle point of the camera system.

My question is that this can easily result in the square root of a negative number which will be a complex quantity. How should one interpret the focal length in such a case?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, they first detect a first vanishing point `v1` and then use it to constrain the position of the second vanishing point `v2` that they detect. I thought that it would make sense to try handling the problem of the negative number you mention in your question here, and yes, it actually appears that this is what they do: to quote the last paragraph of section **4.1.3** (page 31) of that thesis:

*... Line which contains the principal point and is perpendicular to line which is
defined by principal point and the first vanishing point has to separate the second vanishing
point from the first one. If the second vanishing point would be on the same side of the
line as the first one, the expression under square-root (
4.9
) would be negative.*